# DOM Manipulation and Alert function behaviour in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am facing below issue while developing a simple javascript game.

**Below is the code  :**

global variable definition :

```
var player1score,player2score= 0;
var activePlayer = '1';
```

**rollDice** function is called as a result of `click event` on a button.

```
var rollDice = function(){

var randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * 7) + 0);
var currentscore = newscore(randomNumber);
console.log("randomNumber",randomNumber);


    if(activePlayer === '1'){      
        document.querySelector("#player1_currentscore").innerHTML = randomNumber;       
    }else if(activePlayer === '2'){             
        document.querySelector("#player2_currentscore").innerHTML = randomNumber;          
    }   

   //below function displays an alert box based on currentscore value .    
   checkwhowins(currentscore);     

}
```

// below function is called from within rollDice and displays an alert box based on current value passed

```
function checkwhowins(currentscore){


     if(currentscore >= 15 ){  

        //console.log('inside if condition ');
        alert('Congratulations Player '+activePlayer+'  !!!! ,  You are a winner with a score of '+currentscore); 

     }

}
```

Issue :

What I have observed is when `checkwhowins` method **DOES DISPLAY ALERT** box , the DOM manipulation made in rollDice function **DOESN'T work.**
Means  :

```
document.querySelector("#player2_currentscore").innerHTML = randomNumber;
```

**doesn't display** current value as **ZERO.**

But  when **checkwhowins** **DOES NOT DISPLAY ALRET BOX** ,

`document.querySelector("#player2_currentscore").innerHTML = randomNumber` works and currentscore gets updated value

Why is this behavior happening ?

I am really not able to understand it .

Why is DOM not getting updated when Alert function is called ?

Comment: When the alert box comes up, the redraw hasn't happened yet. Does the value (seem to) update *after* you close the alert?

Comment: Yes , the value gets updated after alert is closed . How to make value update when ALERT is also called ?

Comment: `activePlayer` is never defined in the `checkwhowins` function.

Comment: what is `randomNumber`

Comment: You should call the checkWhoWins method after updating the dom, I guess there is some issue in the logic. Also I am assuming the variables activePlayer and totalScore are global variables.

Comment: @Yaakov : activePlayer  is a global variable.

Comment: @brk: random number is calculated by using java script function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure of what may be happening but I'd try delaying chekwhowins wrapping it in a timeout:

```
setTimeout( () => checkwhowins(currentscore) , 1000);  // one second delay
```

I guess this would leave breath the DOM to update.